# Does Redux’s useSelector Hook Method Return Reference to the Data Model Instead of a New Object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner in React and Redux. I am using `react 16.9` with `redux 4.0.4` and `react-redux 7.1.1`.

I notice that I can directly access the underlying Redux data model (objects in store) without dispatching actions.

Consider the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function MyComponent(props) {
    const obj = useSelector(state => state.objReducer);
    obj.newProperty = 'foo';

    return <div />;
}
```

When the component is mounted, `newProperty: foo` will be added to `objReducer`.

My understanding is that we should dispatch actions to reducers in order to make changes to the underlying data model.
Also, as stated [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks), "With useSelector(), returning a new object every time will always force a re-render by default." So `useSelector` should return a new object instead of the actual data object, right?

I am wondering why React-Redux's `useSelector` gives developers access to the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

You are mutating the global state with `obj.property = 'foo';` which is an anti-pattern.

`useSelector` is the equivalent to `mapStateToProps` in the "old" react-redux, which was used solely to access the state within a component.

If you change the state by mutations, like you are doing, the reference of the state will not change and your components listening to this state will not re render.

On the other side, if you use `useDispatch()` you have to ensure that you are not mutating the state there too, by returning a new object rather than mutating the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that direct mutation on the global state is actually a thing in the Redux / React-React world. Yes, I do tend to think that this is an anti-pattern, as stated in my question. I am just wondering why they allow it to happen. Is it by design? Does it act as a workaround when dispatching actions is not an option in certain use cases?